# numbers in range (0,1) are counted as 0

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to sum up some numbers, all between 0 and 1; but it counts all of them as 0. For example these are my numbers:

```
0.5943
0.5380
0.5538
0.5590
```

When I try to calculate the sum of them, it returns **0.00**

When I try to calculate the average of them, it returns **#DIV/0!**

When I try to draw a chart of them, it returns just a line with all zero numbers.

How can I make Excel recognize these numbers as they are?
I use Excel 2016 with Windows 10.

Comment: What functions are you using?

Comment: simple functions like `average` or `sum`. It actually does it anyways. It considers any number between 0 and 1 as 0. But It works fine with other numbers.

Comment: I put your data into `A1:A4`: both `=SUM(A1:A4)` and `=AVERAGE(A1:A4)` work as expected.

Comment: When I changed the `.` to `,`, emulating the wrong number format for my locale, as suggested by aPhilRa's answer, I got your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure Excel interprets your values as actual numbers. Use the isNumber() function to check. Like this:

```
=isnumber(yournumber)
```

If you get FALSE then maybe you need to change your decimal point to a comma.

Comment: It's right. I had copied the numbers from **word** and there was sth wrong with the decimal point. When I typed the numbers in Excel it worked. thaks